# selenium webdriver -xpath generation

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am working in selenium webdriver.I have few text boxes whose ids are going to change all the time.

e.g `id=ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_ad39b78c_a97b_4431_aedb_c9e6270134c6_ctl00_wizNotification_ucChangeData_txtAddress1`

but last part remains same always. in above example `wizNotification_ucChangeData_txtAddress1`
i have tried to go with xpath like:

```
//input[contains(@id,'txtAddress1')
//input[ends-with(@id,'txtAddress1')]
```

but while running not able to identify the textarea.

Any suggestions please.
I tried as well with:  `//input[ends-with(@id,'wizNotification_ucChangeData_txtAddress1')]` but no Luck :(

Answer (score 3):

Xpaths are slow in IE because IE does not have native Xpath engine. You should instead use CSS Selector for better performance. As for your case, you can try below css selector which finds an input for which the id ends with txtAddress1

**E[foo$="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar"**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id$='txtAddress1']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

.//input[@id[contains(.,'txtAddress1')]]

Be careful, if is a textarea it won't be detected as an input.

Answer (score 0):

In case of webelements with dynamic Ids, instead of going for Xpath with Ids we can go for other way of finding elements like 'by tagname', CSSlocator,..  it worked for me.